# Systemd unit fails to run a bash script which otherwise works

Tags: command-line, 18.04, server, bash, systemd

I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Merging pool...";

if !(mergerfs -o minfreespace=4G,defaults,allow_other,category.create=ff /media/pool/hdd1:/media/pool/hdd2:/media/pool/hdd4:/media/pool/hdd5 /media/pool/merged/)
then
        echo "Merging failed."
        exit 1;
fi

echo "Done";

exit 0;
```

It is saved in /home/me/scripts/mergePool.sh. 
If I manually run the script like this: `sudo ./mergePool.sh`, it works fine

I made this unit in /etc/systemd/system/mergePool.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Merge all pool drives into one big virtual drive

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/me/scripts/mergePool.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

If I run the unit like this:

```
sudo systemctl start mergePool.service
```

It produces no error and it doesn't work at all.

This is the log:

```
sudo systemctl status mergePool.service
● mergePool.service - Merge all pool drives into one big virtual drive
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mergePool.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Sat 2020-02-29 12:26:07 CET; 6min ago
  Process: 2066 ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/me/scripts/mergePool.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 2066 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Feb 29 12:26:07 junkbox systemd[1]: Starting Merge all pool drives into one big virtual drive...
Feb 29 12:26:07 junkbox bash[2066]: Merging pool...
Feb 29 12:26:07 junkbox bash[2066]: Done
Feb 29 12:26:07 junkbox systemd[1]: Started Merge all pool drives into one big virtual drive.
```

This is quite confusing to me, why doesn't it work when the script is ran by systemd?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what "doesn't work at all", exactly?

Comment: mergerfs should merge the specified partitions and mount them onto the merged dir, but this doesn't happen, the directory remains empty and and is not a mountpoint

Answer (score 1):

While I don't know why your script is failing, I do see a couple of things that should be fixed, which might get you closer to a solution even if they aren't the solution in and of themselves:

- When launching an executable script that has a sha-bang specifying the appropriate shell/interpreter, as in your example, don't call `/bin/bash` explicitly when you want to run the script. Just call the script.
- If and when you actually need to pass commands directly in a bash invokation, the syntax is `/bin/bash -c "<commands to execute>"`. What your example is doing is first running `/bin/bash` with no arguments or commands, then (as a completely separate second command) running your script. In a oneshot type service that shouldn't actually break anything, but do keep in mind that oneshot is the *only* service type that allows more than one command in this way.
- By wrapping a single command in a shell script in this context, all you really accomplish is making things opaque to systemd. Try simply putting your `mergerfs` command directly in the unit file's `ExecStart=` directive (you may need to enclose it in double quotes). That way systemd can capture `mergerfs`'s exit status, and the `journalctl` log will contain any output and/or error messages produced by `mergerfs`. Then if it fails you should have some information as to why.

Note: For example, the .desktop files used for autostarting desktop goodies only accept one command. If you want to, say, autostart a program after a little delay, that one command could be `/bin/bash -c "sleep 10; <program to launch>"` It works because you're actually passing the double-quoted string of commands to bash as an argument, so the only command being run from the .desktop file is bash itself.

Answer (score -1):

You should put the whole thing you want to run into an infinite loop without the exit code and a sleep 15 eg. to make the service ongoing.

Comment: Please expand your answer to give details on how to do this